# How to set `latitude` and `longitude` by current location to `AgmCoreModule`

Tags: angular5

In my app, I am using `AgmCoreModule` for showing the `google map` the problem is, I would like to set the `latitude` and `longitude` by finding the current user location ( country ) how to achieve that?

here is my current hard coded ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { StorageService } from '../../shared/service/storage.service';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    latitude = 51.678418; //instead find current country and latitude
    longitude = 7.809007; //instead find current country and longitude 

}
```

html:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-map>
```

works fine. But I would like to show the users current country location centered on page load. any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

@3gwebtrain improving his code.

```
if(navigator){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( pos => {
this.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
this.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
})
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me:

```
if(navigator){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( pos => {

                this.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
                this.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
                this.server.getCountry(this.latitude, this.longitude ).subscribe(res => {
                    console.log( res );
                    this.setCountry(res);
                });
            })
        }
```

Comment: How does that help anyone? What is server, where is getCountry defined so may ambiguous parts of this answer and is just confusing